Is ‘drop by’ formal language?
Today I had a session with my Japanese language partner and she told me this:

After buying the present for my father's birthday, we dropped by at the bakery to buy cake.

I feel like drop by is informal language. I consulted the Oxford learners dictionary.
No information about formality is given. Therefore I ask the native speaking community here:
Would you consider "drop by" to be informal?

Register aside, at after the verb drop by is uncommon and redundant. We dropped by the bakery and got this or We got this at the bakery.

Isn't what you're really asking us is whether it was inappropriate for her to use anything but the most formal language with you here? How can anyone else possibly answer that sort of personal question in a definitive way? Even supposing that they could somehow do so, then what sorts of citations and references could document such an answer? But @DjinTonic has the right of it: you've mistaken outright ungrammatical language for merely informal language, which is something else altogether.

There's a wide range of formality in English not just a formal/informal binary (although some dictionaries fail to recognise this). Some language is suitable across a wide range of speech and writing (e.g. from broadsheet journalism to the barber shop) while being perhaps not something you use in specific contexts such as drafting laws, writing scientific papers, or welcoming Papal nuncios. "dropped by" was entirely suitable for the context of someone describing their day.

Just a note that "dropped by" is more common in North American usage, whereas in the UK you'd be more likely to say "dropped in on" (and it usually means calling on someone without prior arrangement).

The dropped by ❌ ᴀᴛ elephant is going to trample everyone in the room and they won't even know what squished them.

@tchrist I heard the trumpet of the rogue elephant and added something to my answer earlier. Did I escape injury?

"dropped by at" is not English. In fact, it's pleonastic. The OP is Japanese.  But the at doesn't merit an entire answer.

@YvonneAburrow In North America, dropped in on is also used. But, for this case, we wouldn't say we dropped in on the bakery to buy cake. We'd say: we dropped in on the baker to buy cake.

Drop by is a colloquial phrase meaning to "stop in for a (brief or impromptu) visit or (minor) incidental purpose".

I can drop by the library and return those books for you on my way to the hardware store.
I'll be in town on business tomorrow. Can I drop by your office around noon and take you out to lunch?

This would be comical:

Drop by the White House next Thursday evening --  we're having a little state dinner with a few dignitaries.

And so would this:

I'm going to drop by the hospital and have open-heart surgery.

P.S. The earliest attestation I've found so far (haven't looked much) is in a story by Joel Chandler Harris (of Uncle Remus fame) published in 1895, Mr Rabbit at Home. Its proximity to "I'll ... give you another whirl" shows its register quite clearly:

'Oh no!', says Brother Bear. 'It wouldn't do to call that wrestling. That was only playing. I was just showing you the first few capers: you can't wrestle until you learn how. I'll drop by your house to-morrow morning bright and early, and give you another whirl.'

But drop in on with much the same meaning is attested from the 1770s, if not earlier.
P.S.  Since @tchrist comments that I neglected to address at in the OP's quoted sentence ("drop by at..."), I will say that the "at" sounds wrong to my ear but I've found a handful of 21st and 20th century attestations from native speakers whose writing is otherwise grammatical; so I suppose the verb, for some speakers, works like the verb "stop in".

Those sentences are comical not just because they're informal, but mainly because  they are not brief or impromptu visits.

@PeterShor Yes, they're comical for several reasons: including the fact that the informal register of "drop by" isn't suitable for a state dinner with dignitaries;  and when the visit is task-oriented, the task has to be of relatively mundane and trivial importance, e.g. picking up the dry cleaning, returning library books, getting some milk on the way home from work -- certainly not having open-heart surgery.

We shouldn't confuse the informality of the action/meaning of "dropping by" with the register of the verb. Apart from jest, no one would show up uninvited at a state dinner and say "I was just passing by," "I thought I would drop by," or "I was in the neighborhood anyway." To my ears, "drop by" as a verb isn't any more informal than most other phrasal verbs, if that's what you mean.

@DjinTonic But a Bill Clinton might have extended  the invitation to a Jean Chrétien in that casual, laid back manner. When a verb is used colloquially only with mundane errands, such as a stop at the convenience store to pick up milk, and with informal visits, and never used with matters of great import or events with symbolic significance, the verb itself acquires a register.  A grammarian's academic taxonomy of register will be much broader-brush than a novelist's or a poet's, and grammarians don't get to call dibs on having  the final word. How do you feel about squeak by?

There is probably an informal<--> formal continuum. I would say put out for extinguish and drop by for visit unannounced are more formal than squeak by for succeed by a narrow margin. Phrasal verbs have a more informal register than their Latinate/Greek counterparts. It's rather that it's uncommon to need the verb drop by in many formal settings.

“Dropped by” is frequently used in the diary Ronald Reagan kept while president: “ The King & Queen of Sweden dropped by for a brief visit. They are here for personal reasons not an official visit.” (In fact no one “drops by” a president.)

@TimR: If for whatever reason, someone did drop by the White House state dinner (because they thought that was acceptable), then how would one formally communicate that this is what happened? Formal/informal language refers more to the relationship between the speaker and the recipient of the communication, not what was in the mind of the third party who the speaker is referring to.

Yes, there are degrees of informality and formality, so a continuum is a decent way to conceptualize it. But I would suggest that register can be approached from a sociolect angle too. For example, consider legalistic register,  academic register, bureaucrat / policy wonk register,  business writing register, military register,  sports broadcaster register, logician register, gangster register, street punk register, and so on.

@Flater  "How would one formally communicate that this is what happened?" Presumably a White House communications director would  have to rise to the challenge and find some diplomatic way to say "The Prime Minister  showed up at the state dinner dressed for a golf outing".  But the action itself is not the issue; it's the aptness of the language to the situation. The White House communications director, unless trying to inject some humor, wouldn't say to the press that some dignitaries were going to be "dropping by".

@flater "made an unannounced visit"  is a common phrasing.

This answer is incomplete because it does not address and in fact neglects all mention of the ungrammaticality of the proffered example: dropped by ❌ ᴀᴛ.

@tchrist The question is very clear. "Is ‘drop by’ formal language?" "I feel like drop by is informal language." "Would you consider "drop by" to be informal?" The same question stated three different ways, and none of them include the "at."
It's clear that the "at" in the quote was not of interest to the OP, and the example sentence was not meant to be an ideal example, but was a real-world quote from a third party. If you want to correct the OP's language partner's grammar, that's something to address in the question, not in these answers.

@tchrist, drop by at is indeed unusual, but it is not entirely unheard of, so how one will react to it depends on where precisely one is on the prescriptivism-descriptivism spectrum. (I suspect that those who use that formulation think of drop by as one seamless concept and don't perceive by in it as a real preposition.) Those who answered this question may have reasonably thought that addressing this matter would be too much of a distraction from its core. If you think that it is important, why don't you post your own answer that does address it?

@jsw29 And it's virtually all very recent, mostly this century. Before the moon landing, it was rarer than hen's teeth, and although it did occur, this was only extremely rarely. If you ngram it you'll see a sizable jump these last 20–30 years before you weed out things like drop by at your convenience, dropping by at odd times, dropped by at least ten degrees which drive all the numbers up unreasonably. I think it's clear from comments that this is still not grammatical to many native speakers today, but I have no idea in what demographic and timeframe the contrary condition applies.

I think we should distinguish the degree of formality/informality in the use of a lexical item from whatever formality/informality lies the meaning of that item.
The Oxford Learner's definition of drop by linked by the OP is "to pay an informal visit to a person or a place." However, I don't think the informality in its meaning makes this phrasal verb different in register from other phrasal verbs as compared their more formal synonyms from the Latin (e.g., put out/extinguish the fire or make out/discern the sign in the fog). In fact, I can't think of a more formal yet succinct way to say "drop by" if that's exactly what I'm trying to communicate (unlike, for example, using the quite informal hang out with us instead of stay/spend some time with us). I wouldn't say something like "We'd be honored if you would like to visit us unannounced anytime" simply because I though the verb "drop by" was too informal. I'll note that Oxford Learner's does have an informal label for the verb hang out.
The frequency of drop by in fiction and everyday speech is no doubt much higher than its frequency in the formal English used in many scientific journals. However, that can be attributed to not often needing this particular verb in scientific prose, rather than authors using another verb because they thought drop by was "too informal" a way of expressing the thought/concept.
I can see why lexicographers don't think that drop by merits a colloquial label any more than thousands of other phrasal verbs that abound in speech and writing.
A good portion of the English vocabulary isn't especially "formal" in register, but wouldn't be out of place if found in formal writing, even if rarely needed.


West Virginia Department of Mental Health
Charleston, August 16, 1967
Dear Mr. Williams: In response to your letter of July 27, 1967, in
which you requested my comments to the Bill S. 276 or The Older
Americans Community Service Program, the Foster Grandparent Program
now in operation in West Virginia makes possible these comments.
The
Foster Grandparent Program now under way in Mental Health has created
meaningful employment for men and women 60 years of age and older
...
If you doubt the value of this Program, I invite you to drop by our
hospitals and center to observe the Foster Grandparents as they work
with the children, as they greet and are greeted by the hospital
staff, and as they make plans for the next day's and the next week's
programs.
Julia Young Hawkins; Older Americans Community Service
Program: [U.S. Senate] Hearings


May 19, 1975
Honorable Mike McCormack
...
Dear Mr. Congressman:
International Solarthermics Corporation did not have an opportunity to
appear before the subcommittee on solar oversight hearings recently
but we have been advised we could submit material for inclusion in the
record of those hearings.
...
We cordially invite you to drop by and take a look or attend one of our specially tailored seminars in Suite C-540 during that time
period.
C. R. Wilhide; letter to Mike McCormack in Solar Heating and Cooling Demonstration Act of 1974, [U.S. House Committee] Hearings


Good evening, ladies and gentlemen. My name is James E. Alatis, and I
am Dean of the School of Languages and Linguistics and Chair of the
Georgetown University Round Table on Languages and Linguistics.
Georgetown is an institution steeped in its traditions. One of those
traditions, which has become particularly cherished and regularly
recalled since I began chairing the Round Table, is that the Chair
should make very brief remarks to leave sufficient time for the
plenary speakers. So I shall honor that tradition this evening by restricting myself to words of welcome, words of thanks, and a few words of introduction.
...
This year we have instituted a publishers'
exhibition, which is being held in Copley Formal Lounge. Publishers
will be displaying their books and taking orders, so please drop
by, have a cup of coffee, and browse.
...
"Welcoming remarks" in James
E. Alatis (ed.); Georgetown University Round Table on Languages and
Linguistics: Educational Linguistics, Cross-Cultural Communication, and Global Interdependence (1994)

See also "Are all phrase verbs informal?"

I haven't been able to find a dictionary that sanctions the verb *drop by at. Adding at after by seems redundant and therefore sounds unusual, bordering on wrong, to my ears. Use We dropped by the bakery to buy cake or, alternatively, We bought/picked up cake at the bakery.

It is not the meaning that makes its register informal but the fact that it is never used in formal speech.  drop by is a colloquialism.

If we had a large corpus  of formal speech from a variety of sources and we found that, for example, kumquat, lingerie, about face, save face, great uncle, and tens of thousands of other items never appear, does that fact alone make any of them a colloquialism?

No, the absence of a word from formal contexts does not, in and of itself, indicate that the word is being avoided on the grounds of informality. But I'm not basing my statement that it is a colloquialism on its mere absence but on the reason for its absence. It is rightly understood to be a colloquialism.  It has all the earmarks of a slang usage that had traction.

Comparing "drop by" to "kumquat" or "lingerie" is a poor analogy. The others are better, but still not really comparable.

@barbecue I wasn't looking for items analogous to drop by, but simply lexical items you likely wouldn't find in formal writing to point out that an item might not be found because they are, in fact, too colloquial, slang, etc., or simply that they are not needed. As I pointed out, Oxford Lerner's tags hang out as informal, but not drop by. A good portion of the English vocabulary isn't especially "formal" in register, but wouldn't be out of place if found in formal writing.

@DjinTonic If I was writing a formal letter inviting someone to visit location, where I followed the normal conventions of formal English (avoiding contractions, minimal pronouns, etc)  I would not say "drop by." I would use "visit" or maybe "arrive." If I was trying for a more casual, informal style, I would use "drop by" instead.

Surely dropped by ❌ ᴀᴛ should be addressed, shouldn’t it?

@tchrist it was already addressed by DjinTonic in a comment on the question.

@barbecue Comments are never answers. They're mortal ephemera, doomed to die. Our answers must be complete unto themselves here.

@tchrist Regardless, the question includes a direct quote from a third party, and this isn't ELL.

@barbecue, telling someone to drop by differs from a formal invitation not only in style, but also in meaning. A formal invitation is normally for a specific time, and it usually implies that, if one cannot come, one ought to respond with some sort of an excuse. Drop by carries more flexibility as to the time of the visit and whether it will take place at all.

@tchrist I'm not sure if what I've added suffices.

Perhaps it should be noted that a compromise between the two sides of this dispute is possible. One could take the position that the term itself is somewhat informal, but that much of the informality associated with it is the informality of the action that it stands for.

@jsw29 As we know, our vocabulary lies  across a wide range of informality/formality. It can be hard to judge how much to attribute to meaning vs. usage. For me, drop by --unlike hang out--isn't colloquial/informal enough to warrant a dictionary label. If its meaning is needed in more formal speech or prose--"come by at your convenience"--it fits the bill perfectly. It has the degree of informality of the majority of phrasal verbs. We don't have to wait for an invitation to a state dinner or ball  with liveried staff to encounter  "formal" English--it's all around us.

@DjinTonic, I think that one possible ground for thinking of drop by as somewhat informal (while accepting most of the argument made int this answer) is that, if one keeps in mind the primary, literal meaning of drop, there is something playful, cartoonish, about using it as a metaphor for a visit. Drop by does not seem to be in quite the same category as jeans (a clear examle of a word that stands for something informal but it itself not at all informal).

@jsw That thought about the meaning of the base verb drop contributing informality to dropping by for a visit occurred to me to. However, dropping off a child at school (fortunately) doesn't conjure up a clip of Wile E. Coyote plummeting from a cliff. Here, too, I would be hard pressed to find a succinct, more formal alternative to drop off (something)--"deliver something/someone to their destination and continue on your way/route"?

As a constituent intransitive to drop off means to fall asleep and may be considered an idiom because you can't figure it out just looking at each word’s meaning—whereas transitive to drop someone/something off is something completely different. And these are both different from dropping off the edge which is two constituents not one, because off the edge is separate and so that's not any kind of drop off case, just happenstance.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Few dictionaries (for instance, Cambridge Dictionary, Merriam-Webster, Longman, Britannica Dictionary, AHD; Collins has 'British' though others don't) add the caveat about informality, but Wiktionary adds a caveat about register:

drop by [Verb] (colloquial):
to visit informally and spontaneously.
Synonyms: drop in, pop in, stop by, stop in ...

I dropped by on Thursday, but you were out.


Obviously, it is a multi-word verb (Cambridge Dictionary has 'phrasal verb'). It may be (at least superficially) intransitive (as in the example above) or transitive:

We dropped by the bakery on the way home.

...................
[Prompted by tchrist]: There is also the 'complex catenation' available, 'drop NP1 by, or [probably mainly US usage; EA] 'drop by NP1'

drop by: 2. To come over briefly (to someone's location) in order to deliver someone or something. In this usage, a noun or pronoun [is]
used between "drop" and "by" [or a non-pronoun NP after "drop by"].

I'll drop by the tools after lunch.
I was planning on dropping the kids [/them] by at 2 o'clock or so. Is that all right?
My mom is gonna drop her sewing machine [/it] by later so we can work on the costumes.


[Farlex Dictionary of Idioms]
It is debateable whether 'drop NP1 by NP2'

You can drop my parents/them by the store.

should be analysed as complex catenation with a transitivised separable multi-word verb or verb + direct object + prepositional phrase. I'd go with the latter (consider

You can drop them beside / next to / right by the store.)


Yes, very simple and with the other possibilities with the same meaning that  you have posted.

Nothing about dropped by ❌ ᴀᴛ?

British English has a plethora of different register types: formality is not just a spectrum, it's but one among many inter-related spectra. Others include class (also called "U vs Non-U English"), politeness, friendliness, prestige (sometimes called correctness), respectfulness, casualness-of-action (via @DjinTonic's answer)...
For example, there are very informal, low-prestige and yet high-class terms like "golly-gosh", "poppycock", "codswallop", "blotto", "in a bind", "for yonks".
Equally there are perfectly formal, high-prestige words which are low-class: "couch", "lounge", "serviette", "dessert", "toilet" (their high-class, high-prestige forms are: "sofa", "sitting room", "napkin", "pudding", "lavatory" respectively. And "loo" is high-class, low-prestige informal; "lav" is low-class, low-prestige informal).
The Independent lists more of these.
The relationships between the registers for formality, class, etc, all vary regionally, even within the UK, and many are completely different or don't even exist in other English-speaking countries (e.g. the US doesn't really do class), and also change as the years pass, and with tone of voice, and it's all terribly context-dependent. They even vary with your accent: so those with Indian accents often tend to use high-class words, but are just assumed to have learned English abroad, from hyper-formal books; and someone with a Welsh accent using a lot of high-class terms might be considered to be "putting on airs".
Regrettably, I know of no dictionary which goes deeply into this stuff: most only list prestige, through a single word like "informal", "colloquial", "archaic"... so I'm afraid I speak with no real authority here, having no references to back me up: these are just how the phrases feel to me, having grown up with British usage:

"popped in" -> informal; casual-action, low class, cozy politeness.
"dropped by" -> informal; casual-action, high class, friendly politeness.
"stopped by" -> informal; deliberate-action, neutral class, slightly positive politeness.
"briefly visited" -> formal; very deliberate-action, neutral class, slightly cold and distant politeness.

In Japanese terms, these are arranged from uchi to soto. These are all subtle nuances, only really noticeable in comparison to each other: context is far more important, and can completely overwhelm these differences.
American English, at least for Central Texas where I currently reside (though after 10 years I still consider myself a learner of American) doesn't really have a class register so far as I can tell, so it's a bit different:

"popped in" -> informal; perhaps quaintly British?
"dropped by" -> informal; friendly politeness.
"stopped by" -> informal; neutral politeness.
"briefly visited" -> formal; slightly cold and distant politeness.

(aside: stopped/dropped/popped is an interesting trio, making me wonder if they developed as a group. Hopped, too, maybe?)

A valuable contribution. I usually don't approve of unsupported answers, but, like you, I don't know where there is any relevant research.

Thanks! I would be VERY grateful to anyone who can offer references for this stuff... not just because I'd like to link 'em, but because I want to READ them too! :D
Out of caution, I'll bold the point about my speaking with no authority here, though, given the absence of good refs.

But the given example was not dropped by. Rather, it was dropped by ❌ ᴀᴛ.

There is also "stopped by" and "came by."

@tchrist True, I should at least mention it, if only to call out that I'm entirely ignoring it as irrelevant to the question as asked. Edited, thanks!

@DjinTonic True! I considered "came/went by", but decided they didn't have quite the same meaning of actually stopping (and "came" kinda implies the place we're talking about is where we are)... but I didn't think of "stopped by" which is pretty on the nose! And popped/dropped/stopped form an interesting rhyming trio. But where does it fall in the registers? I feel it to be kinda... just as informal, but neutral class, but less friendly/uchi than the other two, but more than "briefly visited". I'll edit it in.

Also added a link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U_and_non-U_English which covers what I'd labelled as "class" here.

Depends upon how you want to define “informal”.  It is certainly not slang, but just as certainly it is not how you would respond to an RSVP request to a formal state dinner from a foreign embassy.
I think a better description of it would be casual.  It’s a normal phrase and it is used casually.

I really like the distinction made by DjinTonic's answer, that it means something casual but is not itself particularly casual. The word "casual" is not itself particularly casual or formal; but one should not act casually at a formal state dinner.
